# WCF Service not responding

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, web-deployment

I am developing a WCF based RESTful web service. One my development machine all my queries work fine, but when I deploy the service to my test website (on the internet) one of my GET functions responds with HTTP Error 400. The web.config on my machine and on the test site are identical.
The contract for the problem function is as follows:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "GetLocationID/{name},{city},{state},{country},{postal}")]
    List<GetLocationIdResult> GetLocationID(string name, string city, string state, string country, string postal);
```

I call this function with the following URL:

```
<URL>/TalLimoService.svc/GetLocationID/null,New%20York,null,null,null
```

The service is deployed to on a site to which I have very limited access. I cannot see the event viewer, for example. The only log I can access is the WCSVC.... log, which give the following:

```
2014-12-04 19:30:49 W3SVC418 P3NWVPWEB113 50.62.160.139 GET /TalLimoService.svc/GetLocationID/null,New+York,null,null,null - 80 - 87.68.28.239 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/39.0.2171.71+Safari/537.36 - - internal.tucansdev.com 400 0 0 1839 421 4281
```

In other words, the call arrived, and got an HTTP 400 response.
Why would this work on my development server, but fail on deployment?

Comment: What diagnostics have you tried?  Have you looked at Event Viewer on the server? Have you tried enabling WCF tracing?  Currently there is not enough information in your question for anyone to give you a definitive answer.

Comment: Because this is hosted on a GoDaddy server, I can't really see the event viewer or logs other than the WCSVC log. I will add the very uninformative data from that log to the question.

Comment: This might help you troubleshoot: http://inaspiralarray.blogspot.com/2013/04/finding-root-cause-of-wcf-exceptions.html

Comment: Adding details to the question such as that it is on a GoDaddy server, and type of server if known would also be useful.  Bob Horn has also given you a blog as to how to enable WCF tracing which you could try.